# Excel dd-MM-YY format formula

Tags: database, excel, datetime-format

i have a excel sheet with mixed date format.
Like 15-05-81 and the normal datetime Format 11/07/1990 00:00:00..when i am importing thses to a Database, The non date format give me a null.Is there anyformaula i can convert the text date to a datetime format ?

Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Highlight the entire date column in your spreadsheet
2. Press Ctrl+H
3. Enter find what: -
4. Enter replace with: /
5. Click replace all

This will convert "11-07-90" into "11/07/90".

You may run into problems if the date to be converted has the wrong order also (ie. dd-mm-yy would result in dd/mm/yy which is wrong, the standard format is mm/dd/yy).

Comment: This only change the text .. not the cell type ..